# How to differentiate "#id.class" from "#id .class" in SCSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass

How could I, with SCSS, make the difference between :

```
#id.class {
  color: red;
}
```

and :

```
#id .class{
  color: blue
}
```

Because I need something like :

```
#id {
  .class {
    color: red;
  }
  ' ' + .class {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think dystroy should get the credit for this one.

Comment: I think Denys should get the credit for this one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need `&` to reference to the parent of a selector.

[Documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#referencing_parent_selectors_)

```
#id {
  .class {
    color: red;
  }
  &.class {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `&` :

```
#id {
  .class {
    color: red;
  }
  &.class {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```